# Click Through form with Buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, button

i know how to make a click through form but the problem is that i have some buttons in that form and i would like to click them ! but after

```
int initialStyle = GetWindowLong(Handle, -20);
SetWindowLong(Handle, -20, initialStyle | 0x80000 | 0x20);
```

i cant click my from buttons !

Thanks !

i think im not handling the flags right :( in vs2008 i tried it with `BackColor = Color.Red; TransparencyKey = BackColor;` and it worked well but in vs2010 it is not clicking through. for now i'll try to put onmouseover event on my buttons so that i can click them !

Comment: Those style flags don't make sense.  Just set the form's TransparencyKey and BackColor properties to, say, Fuchsia.

Comment: these flags are use to click through the from .. by just setting TransparencyKey and BackColor i can see whats behind my from but i cant click until its on the top !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it the problem i was having with TransparencyKey was with desktop composition in windows 7 the aero style makes it unable to click through the form, just disable the desktop composition and bazinga .. ! you can click through transparent form =D 
and you can also use a code to deactivate the desktop composition if you need help with that ping me !

Comment: In Windows 8, it can't be disabled... :(